# Programming Linux application to play multiple sounds simultaneously

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa

I've got a need to write a Linux application that does the following:

- 1- Continuously play a `WAV` file in the background. So the entire
  time the application is running this background music plays.
- 2- Be able to play short sounds when certain events happen while the background music continues to play.

What is required to mix in the additional event sounds when they happen with the background music so that both are heard at the same time?

I've never written Linux sound code, so this is ALL new to me. I'm assuming that I will need to write to the `ALSA` API? Or some other library that will facilitate this?

If somebody could provide sample code to get me started I would greatly appreciate it. After a few days I will create a bounty and provide a good deal of reputation for sample code that does what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't want to use ALSA API directly. It's hard to use, and not really portable (since ALSA is specific to Linux).

If you are using some specific libraries in your application (like Qt or something like that), there may be already a counter-part sound library for playing sounds.

If you are looking for a good, general-use sound library, I suggest you take a look at [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). It's quite nice, small and portable; very popular for games. They have quite a nice [example code](http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/usingsound.html) on their site to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will look into SDL.

Comment: Not entirely true that ALSA isn't portable: [4Front](http://developer.opensound.com/) provides an ALSA interface atop OSS named [SALSA](http://opensound.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/opensound/opensound/file/tip/lib/libsalsa/) (not to be confused with the lightweight alsalib known as [SALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/SALSA-Library)).

Comment: So I may be able to use SDL_mixer. Can it be used standalone? Or will I need to link in the SDL library as well as the SDL_mixer library?

Comment: If you are linking against shared library, then `SDL_mixer` should be enough (as long as you don't use some libsdl calls as well yourself). However, when building Linux applications you should always use `pkg-config` to know what to link to, i.e. `pkg-config --cflags --libs SDL_mixer`.

Answer (score 0):

For the part of playing sounds, one library that I used which is easy to learn, use and has a good example in its documentation is [fmod](http://www.fmod.org/fmod-downloads.html). The documentation that comes with the download has a very easy to understand example which you can modify and get your sounds played very quickly.

Comment: Threads are usually a bad design. It makes programs very complex, and more CPU-intensive than they ought to be. Sound playing is a non-interactive process — you just supply the data and let the DMA handle it. Not to mention the sound card access library would have to be thread-safe — or otherwise one thread may end up blocking sound card access to the other one.

Comment: Thanks. However, fork() doesn't provide threads. It creates an exact copy of the running programming, instantiates it and continues on execution returning twice, once to the caller and once to the child process. To get threads you would need to use the Pthread library under Linux or native threads under another OS.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake (embarrasing)... I still need to read more about threads... edited, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I will check out fmod.